# allowed user deletion of activity

Tags: java, android

I am putting together an Android app ( Using Android Studio ) where on initial install the user will be asked to make a number of choices and enter some info. After this has been done these option will not be available to the user again. I am looking for guidance on where I can find a tutorial about this, is there anyone that can help? I am trying to understand the process not just wanting a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Understood, thought I had

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

Define a key named `hasAlreadyConfigured`, when users finished the initial choices, set the key value to `true`, otherwise set its value to `false`.

Then in some place, you could read the key value and do different things.

```
if(!hasAlreadyConfigured){
   //display screens for users to choose options
}else{
   //do other things 
}
```

for how to use SharedPreferences, you could google it and lots of samples existed.

Comment: Thanks  I will take a look at doing it this way